# Yii code obfuscator

Tags: php, yii, obfuscation, yii-extensions

I want to obfuscate my Yii coded files.I have seen some online obfuscator for obfuscating PHP files but if I use them on my yii coded files then do not obfuscate functions of my Yii files because in Yii we have to use function actionabc() at place of abc(). Please provide me any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yii uses the PHP magic methods (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

This means that the framework is deriving the function on the class to call at runtime. Its a form of late binding. Php being a scripting language, I suppose this is very late binding.

In short, you can't  You would have to remove all of the code you are try to obfuscate into classes that have NO Yii calls in it. Then you can obfuscate those.